# Como demorar la extracion de datos usando Curl php

Tags: php, curl

Buenos noches amigos hoy me surgió una duda estoy usando Curl para extraer unos datos de una pagina web de esta manera .

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); //visualizar ñ y acentos.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate"); //(aceptación de codificación gzip)   
$response = curl_exec($ch); //almacena el response de la pagina.

curl_close($ch);

if (preg_match('#rel="nofollow" href=[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $response, $datos)) {
    $mp = $datos[1];
} else {
    $mp = 'error';
}
echo $mp;
```

El código es ta bien El problema esta que la pagina donde extraigo los datos tienen que esperar un tiempo para para procesar la información y curl no espera ese tiempo y me extrae los datos null .

La pregunta es existe una manera de hacer que curl espere a que la información este disponible para extraer la pagina.

Pensé usar

> sleed();

Pero realmente no se donde ubicar lo gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo el sitio del que intentas obtener los datos hace uso de Ajax y cURL/PHP no procesa JavaScript. No es que los datos tarden en aparecer, es que no se están ejecutando dichas peticiones y por mucho que esperes no se ejecutarán.

Puedes probar http://phantomjs.org/

Saludos,

Comment: Gracias por el dato y bien ya entiendo el fallo y revisando http://phantomjs.org/ tiene buena pinta pero no entiendo como ejecutarlo en un servidor  ya que es igual a composer .